# How do you install iText 7 for Java without Maven or Gradle?

Tags: java, itext, loggerfactory

Can someone please list all of the jars/downloads required to get iText running along with links to all of the required external dependencies. Some people can't use maven or gradle. Super confusing. After leaving here I'm going to continue my multi-hour hunt for the required jars. Right now, it's complaining about LoggerFactory.

Comment: By the way, I know having to learn some Maven or Gradle can be frustrating. But the time and effort spent there will be well rewarded.

Comment: _"Some people can't use maven or gradle."_ Can you explain why? Is there any organisational restriction in your company stopping you from using it? And are we talking about iText 5 or 7? Any specific release? Is there any sample code you want to build with it?

Comment: I am asking for your code, because when e.g. using [this tutorial example based on iText 5](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html), you do not need any logger factories, only a single JAR. iText 5 releases can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases), iText 7 (which was modularised onto multiple JARs and has changed package names accordingly) from [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases). The ZIP archives contain all JARs you need.

Comment: I think your question is not about iText but about whatever sample code you downloaded from the web, depending on other libraries like Log4J, Commons Logging, Slf4J or so too, trying to build it. Therefore, your question is not worth much without a link to your example project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with iText 7 latest version, you need to download the following jar files as a dependency. Please note that I have pasted all the jar files of iText 7.2.1 however not all of them are mandatory. At minimum, you must have kernel, io and layout as mandatory however other jar file like barcode will be used only when you have a requirement for it, forms will be used only when you are dealing with forms, sign jar will be used only when u have a requirement for signing.

1. repository\com\itextpdf\barcodes\7.2.1\barcodes-7.2.1.jar
2. repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.31\slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar
3. repository\com\itextpdf\font-asian\7.2.1\font-asian-7.2.1.jar
4. repository\com\itextpdf\forms\7.2.1\forms-7.2.1.jar
5. repository\com\itextpdf\hyph\7.2.1\hyph-7.2.1.jar
6. repository\com\itextpdf\io\7.2.1\io-7.2.1.jar
7. repository\com\itextpdf\commons\7.2.1\commons-7.2.1.jar
8. repository\com\itextpdf\kernel\7.2.1\kernel-7.2.1.jar
9. repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.69\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.69.jar
10. repository\org\bouncycastle\bcutil-jdk15on\1.69\bcutil-jdk15on-1.69.jar
11. repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.69\bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar
12. repository\com\itextpdf\layout\7.2.1\layout-7.2.1.jar
13. repository\com\itextpdf\pdfa\7.2.1\pdfa-7.2.1.jar
14. repository\com\itextpdf\sign\7.2.1\sign-7.2.1.jar
15. repository\com\itextpdf\styled-xml-parser\7.2.1\styled-xml-parser-7.2.1.jar
16. repository\com\itextpdf\svg\7.2.1\svg-7.2.1.jar

Comment: Nailed it.  I was missing: repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.31\slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar but the others will come in handy later. Thanks!!

Comment: Like S_G said, some dependencies are optional and not needed in all situations.. The download archives I pointed to in my comments are enough to run core functionality. And like I also said, if you need more dependencies, it is completely dependent on how you use iText. So next time, Sean, please ask questions here the right way, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just prose. And do answer questions, if someone asks you in a comment. You simply ignored my question and advice, even though what I said was correct.